# front controller , Page controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, uipagecontrol, front-controller

what is the difference between front controller and page controller? which is the best?

Answer (score 6):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978723.aspx) for front-controller pattern and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649595.aspx) for page controller pattern. And you can get a better idea of how front-controller is implemented in ASP.NET MVC and it's advantages over page controller from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-overview-cs)

These are not two complementary patterns but they both have different implementations. ASP.NET MVC uses front controller pattern where as ASP.NET Web forms are implemented based on the page controller pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's that a front controller architecture has a *single entry point* for all requests whereas a *Page Controller* architecture has *separate entry points* for each request. ASP.NET MVC uses the *Front Controller* architecture. FubuMVC is a .NET front controller architecture. StackOverflow isn't really the right forum to address which is better.

[Here](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2011/01/10/fubumvc-routing-and-the-front-controller-pattern/)'s an over of FubuMVC's front controller pattern.

Comment: "ASP.NET MVC uses the page controller architecture" this is an incorrect statement. ASP.NET MVC uses front controller architecture and so does all the other mvc frameworks ( Monorail, FubuMCV) the page controller is the architecture used by ASP.NET Web Forms.